# IDE (PyCharm) settings for developing with Processing in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: pyqgis, ubuntu, qgis-processing, pycharm, ide

How to setup Python interpreter in IDE to develop using Processing module? I need this not for running from IDE, but to have tips about classes, methods, arguments etc.

- IDE: PyCharm 2016.3 (but example in any IDE will be helpful).
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 (any Linux example will be OK too).

In my current PyCharm settings project interpreter located at: */usr/bin/python2.7* and imports from module *QGIS* works fine, but not from *processing* (red curved underlines):

[image: example of imports]

I've discovered, that *processing* located at */usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing* but don't know what to do with this info.

And second. If anybody knows how to setup python virtual environment with all modules, that needed for QGIS plug-in developing, please tell. It may be helpful too. Especially if I’ll develop standalone app in future.

Comment: Did you try to set QGIS python interpriter or change rpoject root directory in Pycharm [settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html)??

Comment: Yes I've tried. But it didn't help. But I already answered in my question.

Comment: I just follow your steps. Could you include in your answer what libraries and modules do you import to make it work? For the virtual environment, I use conda (miniconda). Are you still interested in it? It is for QGIS plugin development?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’ve found the solution of my main question with help of 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24206781/6400573).

If you need to add some external library, first of all check where it is placed (if it is possible of course). I opened Python console in QGIS and inserted:

```
from processing.core import AlgorithmProvider
AlgorithmProvider.__file__
```

output:

```
'/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/AlgorithmProvider.py'
```

Since QGIS 3.0 AlgorithmProvider is not presented. That's why you can import any other module. For example:

```
from processing.core import Processing
Processing.__file__
```

output:

```
'/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py'
```

So, like I already wrote, in my computer processing module located at */usr/share/qgis/python/plugins*

In PyCharm: *File → Settings → Project:… Project Interpreter*

Click on button to show list of available interpreters. At the bottom click “Show All”. In new dialog window click last button like showed on image.

[image: screenshot of PyCharm dialog]

Then click “+” button and add new path to your external library. I added */usr/share/qgis/python/plugins*

Thats all. Now new library is available in PyCharm.

P.S. If you know something about setting virtual environment, I am still interested in it.

Comment: That work for me, i can import processing. But now i got the error "_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm qgis:Buffer not found", i will keep look around. Thanks!