# IDE PyCharm settings for developing a QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pycharm

How do i setup pycharm to recognize QGIS modules?

- IDE: PyCharm
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- QGIS: 3.8

example of imports

[image]

[this answer is very close to the solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232366/ide-pycharm-settings-for-developing-with-processing-in-linux-ubuntu/336620?noredirect=1#comment549129_336620) but I cannot add the interpreter location

I've found the location of the plugins folder but I cannot see a python executable here

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the "add interpreter" dialogue which I have tried to add the folder location but as you can see it is grayed out. Any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Under windows, using pyCharm with QGIS, you have to start pyCharm like you start qgis. In windows it's a batch file, obviously, may be there is a equivalent shell script you could look at? Ah, and what version of qgis do you use?

Comment: QGIS version 3.8