# Connecting QGIS libraries to external IDE under Linux

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, linux, visual-studio-code

The [official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/ide_debugging.html) on the QGIS site states:

> On Linux there is no additional configuration needed to develop
>   plugins.

However, this is not the case, as after a fresh QGIS install and after making sure PATH values are being read by VS Code correctly, I receive this:

[image: importing qgis libraries fail]

...which suggests there *is* some configuration involved in calling QGIS libraries.

There is a discussion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232366/ide-pycharm-settings-for-developing-with-processing-in-linux-ubuntu) that is PyCharm focused and does not address this problem generically.  (In fact it does not work on new versions of PyCharm CE anyway)

I'm on QGIS 3.10; OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

I have ensured that the interpreter being called in VS Code is 3.7.3 64-bit, which is the same as what QGIS 3.10 is using.

Comment: Define "*after making sure PATH values are being read by VS Code correctly*". What `PATH` values exactly?  Do you mean `PYTHONPATH`? I just do this `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins:/usr/share/qgis/python` (or the equivalent in IDE and does work in PyCharm CE).

Comment: In this case I meant, VS Code imports things by default to /home/username/.local/bin which had to be in my path for VS Code to do things like run the IPython kernel.

Comment: Ok, so I tried this and it worked in VSC - if you put it as an answer, I'll mark it correct and also submit it to the QGIS documentation, because even if it's a small configuration setting, it is one that users need to be aware they have to set in order to get it to work.

Comment: I just found I didn't need to set `/usr/share/qgis/python`, VSCode could import `qgis.*` with no additional configuration (using system python3 and system QGIS 3.10) but not `processing`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode (and PyCharm and `python3`) can import `qgis` with no additional configuration (using system python3 and system QGIS 3.10) but not `processing`.

To be able to import `processing` I needed to set `PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins` and ensure the python interpreter is picking up that environment variable.

- For VS Code I tried a `<workspace dir>/.env` file which worked
- For PyCharm I have it set in my run configs
- For cmd line `python3` I just set it manually (so I don't have a global pythonpath var hanging around) with an alias:

  ```
  alias pyqgis='PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins /usr/bin/python3'

  # i.e.
  $ pyqgis

  Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
  [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import processing
  Application path not initialized
  >>>
  ```

Comment: So this may just be an issue with distro-packaging hell.  I grabbed QGIS 3.10 from the OpenSUSE repos, and VS Code and PyCharm were definitely not able, by default, to import qgis or the processing tools.  Still thanks for the answer, because it got me up and running!